# Spring Stomp @SubscribeMapping for User Destination

Tags: stomp, spring-websocket

I am trying to get notified when an user subscribes to a stomp user destination using @SubscribeMapping annotation. My ideia is to send some initialization data to when it  joins.

Although i am not being able to get this working:

Javascript:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/monitor', function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);    
        });
```

Java side:

```
@SubscribeMapping("/monitor-user{clientId}")
public void init(@DestinationVariable("clientId") String clientId) {
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/user/" + clientId + "/monitor", getOps());
}
```

I tried many mapping combinations such as "/user/monitor-{clientId}", "/user/monitor" (Removing clientId), no success at all.

What is the expected mapping value so this get called?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you rephrase your question please? What's the use case you're trying to implement?
Use case 1: when user Alice subscribes to destination "/foobar", you want a message to be sent to the "/monitor" topic, a special topic for monitoring purposes that receives a message every time a user subscribes to "/foobar".
Use case 2: you want to send initialization data, right away, to Alice when she subscribes to "/foobar".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the client subscribes to the "/user/monitor" queue, the server @SubscribeMapping annotation must be to "/user/monitor" and not to "/user/monitor{something}".

The server can understand what client is depending on your authentication scheme. If you use a sockjs websocket you can use HTTP authentication, and hence leverage Spring Security, and add a "Principal" parameter to your function that will hold user information:

```
@SubscribeMapping("/monitor")
public void init(Principal p) {
    String user = p.getName();
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(user, "/monitor", getOps());
}
```

If you don't use http authentication you may send the server the user info, for example adding a custom STOMP header that can be accessed from the server using a SimpMessageHeaderAccessor:

```
@SubscribeMapping("/monitor")
public void init(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor accessor) {
    String user = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("userid");
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(user, "/monitor", getOps());
}
```

Another way could be to subscribe to a different queue name which contains the user information (and this maybe was your proposal). The client must use a code similar to:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/byUser/'+userId, function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);    
});
```

so that the server can access it this way:

```
@SubscribeMapping("/byUser/{userId}")
public void init(@DestinationVariable String userId) {
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(userId, "/monitor", getOps());
}
```

but in this case keep in mind that that queue is public and hence other clients can access their messages if they knows other client names.

Comment: In your second code example, the `convertAndSendToUser()` method will convert the call to `/user/{userId}/monitor`. Spring knows how to find the connection from a Principal name, but how would it find the connection from a custom header it never knew about?

Comment: Just for info, some external broker like RabbitMQ doesn't support slashes after `/topic/*` for example this is invalid  `/topic/custom/subcustom`, I had to change them to  `/topic/custom.subcustom`.